# Getting started with Geotools?

Tags: geotools, references

I want to get full guidance for using geotools from scratch in Java language.

Can you show me the path or give me the suggestions about where I can start this?

I am an intermediate level of java programmer.

I want the complete tutorials link of geotools working in java language.

Answer (score 4):

You can start with [GeoTools tutorials](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/), which is helpful for beginners. It provides an introduction to GIS workshop making use of examples from GeoTools and other Java libraries.